# How are azure terraform variables applied for multiple tf files processed together?

Tags: azure, variables, terraform-provider-azure

For Azure Terraform:

If a variable is declared in a tf file will this value be applied to same variable in other tf files processed together?  Why is there a default value associated with a variable statement?

If I made a tfvars file:
cidrs = [ "10.0.0.0/16", "10.1.0.0/16" ]

Can cidr be used as below for subnet id?  Not really understanding usage syntax?
        subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.subnet.id}"
        subnet id                     = cidr

What exactly is the "Default" function when used with variables?  See below:

```
    variable "prefix" {
         type = "string"
         default = "my"
 }

    variable "tags" {
         type = "map"
         default = {
            Environment = "Terraform GS"
            Dept = "Engineering"
   }
}

     variable "sku" {
         default = {
            westus = "16.04-LTS"
            eastus = "18.04-LTS"
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several questions there. the easy one: `default`:

> The variable declaration can also include a default argument. If
>   present, the variable is considered to be optional and the default
>   value will be used if no value is set when calling the module or
>   running Terraform. The default argument requires a literal value and
>   cannot reference other objects in the configuration.

For the other question, refer to this example: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/subnet.html#attributes-reference

So in short, to use the existing subnet cidr, you need to refer to it like this:

```
azurerm_subnet.%subnetname%.address_prefix
```

subnet name, however, cannot be equals to a cidr, because it doesnt allow for `/` inside of the name. you can use something like this though: 10.0.0.0-24